# Hybrid/Membership Tables

Tags: logic

Can someone give me an overview of how to do Membership tables?

This question for example: Use a hybrid truth/membership table to show that if **A ⊆ B** and **B ⊆ C** then **A ∩ B ⊆ C.**

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about hybrid membership/truth tables, however from the name I can imagine that they should look something like this. We inlcude if $x$ is in some certain set or not and then fill if it is possible (true or false) for the sets to be the coreponding subset in that case. Note that the first three collumns are to cover all cases of wether an element belongs to some sets or not, and column 4 is a consequence of this. The rest of the collumns are then true or false depending on wether it is possible for the subsetrelation to hold in this case.
$$ 
\begin{array}{||c||c||c || c|| c || c||}\hline
A & B & C & A\cap B& A\subseteq B & B\subseteq C & A\cap B\subseteq C\\
\hline
x\in  & x\in & x\in & x\in& T & T & T \\
\hline
x\in  & x\in & x\notin & x\in & T & F & F \\
\hline 
x\in  & x\notin & x\in & x\notin & F & T & T \\
\hline 
x\in  & x\notin & x\notin & x\notin & F & T & T \\
\hline 
x\notin  & x\in & x\in & x\notin & T & T & T \\
\hline
x\notin  & x\in & x\notin & x\notin & T & F & T \\
\hline
x\notin  & x\notin & x\in & x\notin & T & T & T \\
\hline
x\notin  & x\notin & x\notin& x\notin & T & T & T \\
\hline
\end{array} 
$$
We see from the table that each time both $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ is true, then $A\cap B\subseteq C$ is true, thus we conclude what we should prove.